# web deploy does not include all .css files in the deployment package

Tags: webdeploy

my web application uses a .css file.   However when I use web deploy to publish the application to a web  deploy package, the style sheet is omitted from the .zip file.

Comment: What version of ASP.NET?  Are you sure the css file is part of the project (not just on the file system)?

Comment: Here is a copy of the project:  I don't know how to add a pix...   When I do a show all on the project, the file ColorPicker.css shows up with a  check mark, but does not show up in the web deploy zip file.

Comment: Figuring out which version of asp.net is, for me, non trivial. How do I do that?